# Search in multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, search

Having the following table schema:

```
id | english_name | russian_name | year
---------------------------------------
 5 |   The Book   |    Kniga     | 2008
```

and the given input: `Kniga 2008`;

Is it possible to reproduce the following steps?

- Search `russian_name` for EXACT MATCH. If matched, return the row;
- If no matches, search `english_name` for EXACT MATCHES.
- If still no matches, like in the following case (input is `Kniga 2008`), then try to look among columns and see if there is ANY COMBINATION of columns matched. In this particular case `russian_name` and `year` will match.
- Ignore characters like `-`, `/`, `:` so if the given input is: `The Book / Kniga 2008` or is `The Book : 2008`, the results should still contain the row above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not pretty, but:

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE russian_name = ? OR english_name = ? OR CONCAT(russian_name, ' ', year) LIKE ? OR CONCAT(english_name, ' ', year) LIKE ?
```

where the query string is set to the first two question marks, and the second and third as:

```
'%' . str_replace ( ' ', '%', $query ) . '%'
```